# Unable to refresh TableView after deleting a row data

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I am deleting a row data from TableView but it is not updating after the action. 
I am updating the values, that is working fine. But only if I delete entire row the problem arises. Help. Using JavaFx.

I am removing that entry by this:

observablelist.remove(selectedIndex);

And setting the contents again:

tvTable.setItems(observablelist);

I doubt, if any code can help this question.

Comment: people are going to need to see some code to be able to help you

Comment: All you should need is the `observablelist.remove(selectedIndex);` line. That will be enough. As mentioned, post some code which shows the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In order to help you, I have created a sample. Please refer to

[TableViewDeleteSample](https://gist.github.com/abhinayagarwal/9735744)

Hope, it helps !